# capture parameters passes to stub in powermockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, stubbing

How can I capture (for assertion purposes) the parmeters passed to a static stub method call?

The methodBeingStubbed looks like this...

```
public class SomeStaticClass{
protected static String methodBeingStubbed(Properties props){
...
```

I am stubbing the method call because it i need to verify that it gets called...

```
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(SomeStaticClass.class, "methodBeingStubbed")).toReturn(null);
PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
```

But I now also want to know what properties were passed to this "methodBeingStubbed" and assert it is as expected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the call to `verifyStatic`, you'll need to actually call the method you're trying to verify, as in [the documentation here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-use-argument-matchers):

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Static.class);
Static.thirdStaticMethod(Mockito.anyInt());
```

At that point you can use Mockito [argument captors](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html), as demonstrated (but not tested):

```
ArgumentCaptor<Properties> propertiesCaptor =
    ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Properties.class);

PowerMockito.verifyStatic(SomeStaticClass.class);
SomeStaticClass.methodBeingStubbed(propertiesCaptor.capture());

Properties passedInValue = propertiesCaptor.getValue();
```

If you're used to `@Mock` annotations, or you need to capture a generic (as in `List<String>`), you may also be interested in using the [`@Captor`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Captor.html) annotation instead.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  The interesting (and somewhat counter-intuitive) thing here is that unlike setting up the mock/stub whcih goes before the testing of the logic, the code to setup the capture goes  afterwards.

Comment: Full code please?  I'm confused by the order of your method calls. I used your code exactly as is and it failed. It told me the method wasn't invoked.

Comment: @Stevers I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Full code please"; in absence of a full example in the question, are you asking me to write an entire example setup and then an entire test for the example setup? I'm not sure I could do better than the documentation that already exists (to which I've updated the link). If you have an example that isn't working, that already exists as a MCVE, it sounds like an excellent case for a separate question that links to this one.